# Not returning child Count from databasesnapshot Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 searchbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (id==valid)
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getjcard.this,"Invalid ID ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                return;
           }
           else
            {
                jcid=id;
            }

            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query query = reference.child("maindata").orderByChild("Registration No").equalTo(jcid);
            foundjc=0;
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                         dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        foundjc= (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                        if (foundjc>0)
                        {  Toast toast = 
                             Toast.makeText(getjcard.this,"Records Found  "+ foundjc, 
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();}
                        else
                        {  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getjcard.this,"no data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();}
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

with help of above code trying to get number of records having particular id jcid with onclick listener on button  but When Record are present in database it return Data found 
But it dose nothing when there is no record present in Database

Data Structer
      {

```
  "maindata" : [ {

"Applicant Name" : "राजेन्‍द्र राम",
"Applicant No" : "1",
"Bank Code" : "112",
   "Block Name" : "BHAISIACHHANA",
"Branch Code" : "623",
"Branch Name" : "baadecheena",
"District Name" : "ALMORA",
   "Name of Primary Account Holder" : "Rajendra Ram",
"Panchayat Name" : "ALISUPYAL",
"Registration No" : "UT-07-008-001-001/103",
"Sno" : "1",
"State Name" : "UTTARAKHAND"
  }, {
 "Applicant Name" : "पार्वती देवी",
"Applicant No" : "1",
"Bank Code" : "112",
   "Block Name" : "BHAISIACHHANA",
"Branch Code" : "623",
"Branch Name" : "baadecheena",
"District Name" : "ALMORA",
 "Name of Primary Account Holder" : "PARWATI DEVI",
"Panchayat Name" : "ALISUPYAL",
"Registration No" : "UT-07-008-001-001/121",
"Sno" : "2",
"State Name" : "UTTARAKHAND"
  }]
  }
```

Comment: Please provide us the database structure.

Comment: You can get this database structure (as text, no screenshots please) by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: '{
 
       "maindata" : [ {
       "Applicant Name" : "राजेन्‍द्र राम",
       "Block Name" : "BHAISIACHHANA",
        "Branch Code" : "623",
        "Panchayat Name" : "ALISUPYAL",
    "Registration No" : "UT-07-008-001-001/103",
    "Sno" : "1",
    "State Name" : "UTTARAKHAND"
  }, {
     "Applicant Name" : "पार्वती देवी",
    "Applicant No" : "1",
      "Branch Code" : "623",
       "Panchayat Name" : "ALISUPYAL",
    "Registration No" : "UT-07-008-001-001/121",
    "Sno" : "2",
    "State Name" : "UTTARAKHAND"
  }]
}'

Comment: Please edit your post with your data structure.

Comment: You getting 0 when using `getChildrenCount()` beacause none of your `Registration No` is equalTo `jcid`. Are you sure you are searching for the correct value?

Comment: thanks alex for help i found the solution actually 'if (foundjc>0)' is in side (dataSnapshot.exists()) statment putting it outsideget me required result t

Comment: Good news, cheers!